# How can I make the Intershop Studio faster?

Tags: intershop

We're using the latest published version, and with our code is painfully slow. Takes ages to start, working with pipelines is sluggish. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the latest Eclipse-version and add the Intershop Studio as an extension on top.

Here is how I did it on Windows:

- install the latest Eclipse version with a Java Dev environment
- modify eclipse.ini to have **a lot** of memory

  -Xms512m

  -Xmx8048m

  -XX:PermSize=512m

  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
- install Intershop Studio as additional software from https://support.intershop.com/estudio/ (Help->Install New Software)
- run Eclipse from a command line configured by environment.bat
- configure your Gradle environment in the Intershop settings (Window->Preferences->Intershop Studio)
- import cartridges
- start working

If you have more/better ways to get things faster, I'm happy to ready your answer!

Comment: I didn't need to run Eclipse from a command line with populated variables from `environment.bat`. I just added the necessary Java VM via Installed JREs and referred to my ICM server environment via `intershop.properties`

Comment: Details please! :) Any hint for running the latest Eclipse with Java8 would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM needs enough space.
change IntershopStudio.ini:
-Xmx4096m

Comment: It needs much more :) I'll add this so my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**To add to Sven Bluege`s answer**

In case you come across this error when trying to use the Gradle plugin that ships with eclipse:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.Package[] java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @572206fe
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.<init>(JavaMethod.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.<init>(JavaMethod.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaReflectionUtil.method(JavaReflectionUtil.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.<clinit>(FilteringClassLoader.java:43)
    ... 49 more
```

You need to add this to your eclipse.ini:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

because new eclipse versions only work with up-to date JVM as well.